# PHP Symfony apps on OSX El Capitan apache

Tags: php, macos, apache, symfony

I have installed the symfony_demo application on El Capitan (10.11.2)

If I run the inbuilt PHP server as follows:

```
php app/console server:run 127.0.0.1:8111
```

the demo application is Live at localhost:8111

but if I access the application via El Capitan's inbuilt apache instance (by copying it into my `<user>`/Sites directory), I just get a directory listing.

Note that I do have PHP enabled on apache, and other PHP-based applications run through apache as currently configured (e.g. Joomla).

What more configuration of apache do I need?

**Addendum:**

I am running the Server version of the OS.  I read that there exists another apache configuration file at: `/Library/Server/Web/Config/apache2/httpd_server_app.conf`
But uncommenting the vhosts .conf and .so directives and restarting 'Websites' via the Server app in this file made no difference to the behaviour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Success!
The pivotal information here is that the Server version of OSX has it's own configuration *which disables .htaccess redirection by default*.

After finding the setting in Server > Websites > Server Website (edit) > Edit Advanced Settings > "Allow overrides using .htaccess files
And restarting Websites, the symfony demo works fine at http://localhost/symfony_demo/web/

n.b.: No need for vhosts - that's merely a convenience

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to uncomment few lines in your `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`.  Remove the `#` in front of the following lines if it's there (these lines are in different parts of the file):

```
LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so

LoadModule vhost_alias_module libexec/apache2/mod_vhost_alias.so

Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Next, you can edit `/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` to define your virtual hosts. For example if your project is located in `/Users/username/Sites/symfony` (replace "username" with your username, and "symfony" with you project directory):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName symfony.dev

    DocumentRoot "/Users/username/Sites/symfony/web/"
    <Directory "/Users/username/Sites/symfony/web/">
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

In the example I used a fake domain `symfony.dev`. If you want to use it you'll need to add it to your `/etc/hosts` file (add a new line there):

```
127.0.0.1 symfony.dev
```

After changing apache's configuration don't forget to restart it:

```
sudo /usr/sbin/apachectl restart
```

You might need to adapt the vhost config to your needs. Read [more about configuring the web server in the Symfony documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/web_server_configuration.html).

Comment: I found that article too (prior to posting), and I tried that method - but I just get a directory listing of the Sites folder at http://symfony.dev - it seems like httpd-vhosts.conf is being ignored completely despite the changes I made..  Is there anything else that could be misconfigured?

Comment: Not sure which article you've followed. What I listed here is all that should be required. If you're getting a listing than you missed a step. Make sure the paths are correct (notice the web dir), and the php module is enabled. Don't forget to restart apache after changing its config.

Comment: this is the article https://dab.io/posts/start-with-symfony-on-mountain-lion.html